# Unable to execute commands in Chromecast debugging Console

Tags: remote-debugging, chromecast, chrome-remote-debugging

I was able to work with the Chromecast remote debugger (on port 9222) until few days ago. Suddenly it stopped working, each time I write a js command on che Console prompt and hit "Enter" all I get is a new line and the command does not get executed. Is there any setting I'm not able to find?

I already rebooted my PC, restored the Chromecast to the factory settings, tested with different browsers, but I'm not able to get it working any more.

I also tried to debug the Chromecast app using the Chrome remote debugger (chrome://inspect) but it only works when launched from computers connected to the WiFi network, Chrome does not detect the Chromecast from computers connected with the cable, even if they are on the same subnet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there's an existing [issue #821](https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=821) logged in google-cast-sdk Issues tracker.

Based from the thread, the current workaround that works is to access devices with `chrome://inspect#devices`.

Hope that helps!